# Get frequencies of each number/character

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with two columns, containing numbers separated by comma/space and other with the frequency of it's occurrence.

Data looks like this (Column wise);

```
Medication        Number 
1,2,10,11            3 
1,4,5,14,6           1
2,3 12,11            2
2,3                  1
1,3,5                5
```

I want the number of occurrences of each number. 
For Ex:

```
 Character/Number  Frequency
            1            9 
            5            6
```

What I have tried;

- Used "COUNTIF" for all the numbers, but the single digits are creating problem as they also appear in double digits.
- Separating them out in columns and then counting.

How do I do this using Excel/SPSS?

Comment: This is not very clear to me; why does 5 have a frequency of 6 instead of 2?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Agreed.  His sample output is not clear, though the question itself seems clear.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler 5 has appeared once in second row and 5 times in 5th row. That makes it's frequency to 6. Actually, (1,4,5,14,6), (1,3,5) are the sets. But I need frequency of each numbers. i.e. the number of occurrences in any of such sets.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it could hardly be less clear if it was a comedy sketch deliberately setting up a misunderstanding. Asking for the frequency of numbers with a column called 'Number' (unrelated) which gives a frequency (unrelated), asking about counting the "numbers/characters" - where characters doesn't include either of the two characters mentioned - space and `,`; talking about COUNTIF and single digits, while talking about "characters", *and* giving an output example where the quantity of the character `1` in the data matches the desired frequency - but that's also unrelated...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I was marked correct, then it was taken away.  I guess even the OP can't be certain if my answer is right, because he is uncertain of the OP.  Ever see "Who's on First" starring the Three Stooges?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen haha, I have seen it yes. :)  I like your approach, and now I think I understand this - `medication entry, repeated /Number/ of times, then split by (space or comma), then count the frequency of numbers` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi...My apologies for so many confusions and appreciate your efforts in understanding my problem. To clear confusions,I have numbers, characters, commas and spaces in my original data. :) Your answer is right and serves my purpose. I unchecked the right mark by mistake. (I am a new user).

Comment: @RaviGS No issues, your question was way better than average for new users by the way.  Only the sample data did not match the output exactly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, Sorry to bother again. When I apply the solution suggested, I get the number of times each digit has appeared (For ex number 1) . But it also includes the appearance in number 11,12,13 and so on. How do I avoid that?. In the output I've shown, 1 appears thrice in first row, once in 3nd row and 5 times in 5th row which makes it's frequency to 9. I hope you got the problem. Else I'll edit the whole question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result can also be achieved using one liner array formula:

```
=SUM(LEN($A$2:$A$6) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$6,D2,"")))
```

[image]

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you wish to find the frequency of a number having two or more digit i.e *number > 9* then use array formula as:

```
=SUM(LEN($A$2:$A$6) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$6,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of occurrences of each digit in the `Medication` column, one trick you can use is to compare the length of the text in the cell against the length of the text with the digit of interest removed.  Consider the following screen capture:

[image]

The formula in cell `C2` compares the length of `A2` (9) to the length of `A2` with all ones removed, to give a count of 4.  This can be repeated for each digit of interest.

If you wanted to include the digits in the `Number` column as well, then you can just add this to the formula.

Comment: This will definitely help. Thanks.